# How to check for non-number inputs in calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator

Just started learning C and tried to make a calculator to test myself. I thought it would be a fun challenge to make it so:

1. the program prints an error message to the user if the input(s) is not a number
2. the user can input a number again, without shutting down the program

What I've learned in C so far is:

- printf, scanf
- data types
- if statements
- loops
- functions

My question is, is it possible to accomplish the task with the knowledge mentioned above. If it is, what is that solution? (I've been stuck on this for quite a while now, so I hope me giving up on doing it myself is acceptable). If it's not, what do I need to learn to be able to do it?

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

float num1;
float num2;
float answer;
char operation;
int isNumber;           //1 means true, 0 means false
char restart;


int main ()
{
  printf ("Please enter the first number: ");
  isNumber = scanf("%f", &num1);
  while (isNumber == 0)
    {
       printf("Please enter a valid number: ");
       isNumber = scanf("%f", &num1);
    }
    
    //This just keeps reapeating the printf message.
    //Also, I just wrote the code for the first input.
    //If it doesn't work for this one, no point in writing it for other inputs.

  printf ("Please enter an operation: ");
  scanf (" %c", &operation);
  
  printf ("Please enter the second number: ");
  scanf ("%f", &num2);

  if (operation == '+')
    {
      answer = num1 + num2;
    }

  else if (operation == '-')
    {
      answer = num1 - num2;
    }

  else if (operation == '*')
    {
      answer = num1 * num2;
    }

  else if (operation == '/')
    {
      while (num2 == 0)
    {
      printf ("Cannot divide by 0. ");
      printf ("Please enter another number\n");
      scanf ("%f", &num2);
    }
      answer = num1 / num2;
    }


  printf ("\nThe answer is: %f", answer);
  printf ("\n\nEnter 1 to do another calculation. Enter anything else to quit: ");
  scanf(" %c", &restart);

  if(restart == '1')
      main();
  else
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: @xing man that was a quick response. Thanks a lot! Guess I need to read up on different scanf arguments :) If you post it as an answer I can mark it as best.

Comment: If you want to do strict parsing, it's best to start by reading an entire line of input with `fgets`. So first you need to learn about `fgets`, and then learn about the character classification functions in `<ctype.h>`, e.g. the `isdigit` function. `scanf` is a quick and dirty input method. Trying to use it as a strict parser generally ends in a mess.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for that as well! I'll make sure to learn that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` only reads input that matches the format specifier (in your case this is `%f`). Characters that do not match the format specifier causes `scanf()` to stop scanning and causes `scanf()` to leave the invalid characters in the `stdin` buffer.

In your while loop if a invalid character is entered it will get stuck in the `stdin` buffer. This invalid character will then get read by the next `scanf()` call in the loop, which will also leave it in the `stdin` buffer. This will continue, again and again, resulting in an infinite loop.

As you might be able to tell `scanf()` is a unreliable and quick - yet not very robust way to take input.

To fix it you could use a hacky solution like this:

```
while ((scanf("%f", &num1)) != 1)
{ 
       printf("Please enter a valid number: ");
     
       int c; 
       while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

// while loop "eats up" any characters
// that scanf has left in stdin buffer
```

Instead of `scanf()` i reccomend you get familiar with a function such as `fgets()` to take input. Then you can use a function like `sscanf()` to parse the input to see if it is a float.

As a beginner, while you are learning C, it is fine to use `scanf()`.  But as you delve deeper into C and write more complicated pieces of software you must consider using safer and more robust alternatives to unreliable functions like `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

To well handle user input, consider dropping all `scanf()` calls.  To read a *line* of user input, use `fgets()`.

> How to check for non-number inputs

Create a helper function.

Read a line of text into a buffer and parse with `sscanf()` or `strod()`.  `sscanf()` is OK and used below.  `strod()` is better, yet some corner cases are beyond what a learner may appreciate.

```
#define LINE_LENGTH_MAX 400

// Return 1 on success, EOF on end-of-file, 0 on failure
int read_double(double *dest, const char *prompt) {
  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }

  char buffer[LINE_LENGTH_MAX + 1];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }

  int n = 0; 
  sscanf(buffer, "%f %n", dest, &n);
  if (n == 0) {
    // Scanning failed
    return 0;
  }

  if (dest[n]) {
    // Yet there was extra junk at the end
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

More advance code would used `strtod()` and detect lines longer than `LINE_LENGTH_MAX`.